# Compare Dynamic range to a dynamic range in another workbook and get value

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to compare four cell values to a dynamic range in another sheet. The four cells values I'm comparing against in the other workbook are employee ID, Pay Rate, Department, and customer ID. If they match return value.

I would like to use VBA code only, since I had previously used a formula.

The formula I used was the following:

```
=INDEX($L$2:$V$60000, MATCH(1,  (C2=$O$2:$O$60000) * (D2=$P$2:$P$60000) * (E2=$Q$2:$Q$60000) * (f2=$r$2:$r$60000),0),10)
```

This formula was updated manually and the data I was comparing I had to paste it to the workbook that had the data with the value I wanted to extract. That value was located in column 10.

Please help me automate this step. If I was not clear enough please let me know. Also, I will only like to use statements not application functions if possible.

Thank you in advance to all.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function MatchData() As Variant
On Error GoTo Proc_Error

    Dim rngData             As Excel.Range
    Dim scpData             As Scripting.Dictionary

    Dim arrNeed             As Variant
    Dim arrDates            As Variant
    Dim arrResult           As Variant

'    Dim path                As String
    Dim lngRow              As Long
    Dim intCol              As Integer
    Dim strLookup           As String
    Dim strReturn           As String

' load the GetDates data into an array. Function looks for source worksheet, starting row, number of columns to return and starting column
    arrDates = GetData(wsGetDates, 2, 4, 4)      '(start with Row 2, column 4, return 8 columns)
' build a scripting dictionary object over the array, starting with column 1 for four columns. Use a period as a delimiter.  Essentially an index over the array
    Set scpData = Loadscp(arrDates, 1, 4, ".")

' put the values to find into another array.
    arrNeed = GetData(wsNeedDates, 2, 4, 3)   '(start with Row 2, column 3, return 4 columns)
    ReDim arrResult(LBound(arrNeed, 1) To UBound(arrNeed, 1), 1 To 2)

' Loop through the data needing dates to find matching rows in GetDates
    For lngRow = LBound(arrNeed, 1) To UBound(arrNeed, 1)
    ' build a key matching the index built above
        strLookup = arrNeed(lngRow, LBound(arrNeed, 2))
        For intCol = LBound(arrNeed, 2) + 1 To UBound(arrNeed, 2)
            strLookup = strLookup & "." & arrNeed(lngRow, intCol)
        Next intCol

    ' if the key is found in the index, return the corresponding value in the 7th column (U)
        If scpData.Exists(strLookup) Then
            arrResult(lngRow, 1) = arrDates(scpData.Item(strLookup), 7)
            arrResult(lngRow, 2) = arrDates(scpData.Item(strLookup), 8)
        Else
            arrResult(lngRow, 1) = "No Match"
            arrResult(lngRow, 2) = "No Match"
        End If
    Next lngRow

' Finally, push the results back to the sheet needing the data
    wsNeedDates.Range("I2").Resize(UBound(arrResult, 1) - LBound(arrResult, 1) + 1, _
        UBound(arrResult, 2) - LBound(arrResult, 2) + 1).Value = arrResult

Proc_Exit:

' clean up all the objects
    Set wbNeedDates = Nothing
    Set wsNeedDates = Nothing
    Set wsGetDates = Nothing
    Set wbGetDates = Nothing
    Set scpData = Nothing
    Set rngData = Nothing

    Exit Function

Proc_Error:

    Select Case Err
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Error " & CStr(Err) & ": " & Err.Description
            Resume Proc_Exit
    End Select

End Function
'I normally put these in a separate utility module, they just get in the way of me looking at the logic...

Public Function GetData(ByVal wksCurr As Excel.Worksheet, Optional ByVal intTop As Integer = 1, _
    Optional ByVal intCols As Integer = 1, Optional intCol As Integer = 1) As Variant
On Error GoTo Proc_Error

    Dim arrTemp             As Variant

Dim lngLastRow          As Long

    lngLastRow = LastRow(wksCurr, intCol)

    If lngLastRow >= intTop Then
        GetData = wksCurr.Cells(intTop, intCol).Resize(lngLastRow - intTop + 1, intCols).Value
    Else
        ReDim arrTemp(1 To 1, 1 To intCols)
        GetData = arrTemp
    End If

Proc_Exit:

    Exit Function

Proc_Error:

    Select Case Err
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Error " & CStr(Err) & ": " & Err.Description
            Resume Proc_Exit
    End Select

    Exit Function

End Function

Public Function LastRow(ByVal wksCurr As Excel.Worksheet, ByVal intCol As Integer) As Long

    Dim lngLastRow          As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    lngLastRow = wksCurr.Columns(intCol).Find( _
        What:="*", After:=wksCurr.Cells(1, intCol), _
        MatchCase:=False, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).row
    If Err <> 0 Then
        lngLastRow = 0
        Err.Clear
    End If

    LastRow = lngLastRow

End Function

Public Function Loadscp(ByVal varList As Variant, Optional ByVal intCol As Integer = 1, _
    Optional ByVal intCols As Integer = 1, Optional ByVal strDelim As String = ".") As Scripting.Dictionary

    Dim scpList             As Scripting.Dictionary

    Dim arrVals             As Variant

    Dim lngLastRow          As Long
    Dim lngRow              As Long
    Dim intABSCol           As Integer
    Dim intColCurr          As Integer
    Dim strVal              As String
    Dim intRngCol           As Integer

    Set Loadscp = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Loadscp.CompareMode = vbTextCompare

    intABSCol = Abs(intCol)
    If IsArray(varList) Then
        arrVals = varList
    ElseIf TypeName(varList) = "Range" Then
        intRngCol = varList.Column
        lngLastRow = LastRow(varList.Parent, intCol)

        If lngLastRow > varList.row Then
            arrVals = varList.Offset(1, intABSCol - 1).Resize(lngLastRow - varList.row, 1)
        End If
    ElseIf TypeName(varList) = "Dictionary" Then
        Set scpList = varList
        ReDim arrVals(1 To scpList.count, 1 To 1)
        For lngRow = 1 To scpList.count
            arrVals(lngRow, 1) = scpList.Keys(lngRow - 1)
        Next lngRow
    End If

    If IsArray(arrVals) Then
        For lngRow = LBound(arrVals, 1) To UBound(arrVals, 1)
            strVal = arrVals(lngRow, intCol)
            For intColCurr = intCol + 1 To intCol + intCols - 1
                strVal = strVal & strDelim & arrVals(lngRow, intColCurr)
            Next intColCurr
            If Not Loadscp.Exists(strVal) Then
                Loadscp.Item(strVal) = lngRow
            End If
        Next lngRow
    End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how you want to implement this, you didn't give much info.  A bit of VBA that might do it, returning the matching value in column O:

First, in the VBA editor, select Tools, References, and check Microsoft Scripting Runtime; you need this for the scripting library.

The logic to match things up is in this first routine.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function MatchData() As Variant
On Error GoTo Proc_Error

    Dim wbNeedDates         As Workbook
    Dim wbGetDates          As Workbook
    Dim wbNeedDates         As Worksheet
    Dim wsGetDates          As Worksheet
    Dim rngData             As Excel.Range
    Dim scpData             As Scripting.Dictionary

    Dim arrNeed             As Variant
    Dim arrDates            As Variant
    Dim arrResult           As Variant

'    Dim path                As String
    Dim lngRow              As Long
    Dim intCol              As Integer
    Dim strLookup           As String
    Dim strReturn           As String

'    path = "C:\Users\works\Documents\Macros\"
    Set wbNeedDates = Workbooks("Need Dates.xlsx")
    Set wsNeedDates = wbNeedDates.Worksheets("Inactive4Weeks copy")

    Set wbGetDates = Workbooks("Copy of TransactionExportReport.xlsx")
    Set wsGetDates = wbGetDates.Worksheets("TransactionExportReport")

' load the GetDates data into an array. Function looks for source worksheet, starting row, number of columns to return and starting column
    arrDates = GetData(wsGetDates, 2, 8, 4)      '(start with Row 2, column 4, return 8 columns)
' build a scripting dictionary object over the array, starting with column 1 for four columns. Use a period as a delimiter.  Essentially an index over the array
    Set scpData = Loadscp(arrDates, 1, 4, ".")

' put the values to find into another array.
    arrNeed = GetData(wsNeedDates, 2, 4, 3)   '(start with Row 2, column 3, return 4 columns)
    ReDim arrResult(LBound(arrNeed, 1) To UBound(arrNeed, 1), 1 To 2)

' Loop through the data needing dates to find matching rows in GetDates
    For lngRow = LBound(arrNeed, 1) To UBound(arrNeed, 1)
    ' build a key matching the index built above
        strLookup = arrNeed(1, LBound(arrNeed, 2))
        For intCol = LBound(arrNeed, 2) + 1 To UBound(arrNeed, 2)
            strLookup = strLookup & "." & arrNeed(1, intCol)
        Next intCol

    ' if the key is found in the index, return the corresponding value in the 7th column (U)
        If scpData.Exists(strLookup) Then
            arrResult(lngRow, 1) = arrDates(scpData.Item(strLookup), 7)
            arrResult(lngRow, 2) = arrDates(scpData.Item(strLookup), 8)
        Else
            arrResult(lngRow, 1) = "No Match"
            arrResult(lngRow, 2) = "No Match"
        End If
    Next lngRow

' Finally, push the results back to the sheet needing the data
    wbNeedDates.Range("I2").Resize(UBound(arrResult, 1) - LBound(arrResult, 1) + 1, _
        UBound(arrResult, 2) - LBound(arrResult, 2) + 1).Value = arrResult

Proc_Exit:

' clean up all the objects
    Set wbNeedDates = Nothing
    Set wsGetDates = Nothing
    Set wbNeedDates = Nothing
    Set wbGetDates = Nothing
    Set scpData = Nothing
    Set rngData = Nothing

    Exit Function

Proc_Error:

    Select Case Err
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Error " & CStr(Err) & ": " & Err.Description
            Resume Proc_Exit
    End Select

End Function
```

I normally put these in a separate utility module, they just get in the way of me looking at the logic...

```
Public Function GetData(ByVal wksCurr As Excel.Worksheet, Optional ByVal intTop As Integer = 1, _
    Optional ByVal intCols As Integer = 1, Optional intCol As Integer = 1) As Variant
On Error GoTo Proc_Error

    Dim arrTemp             As Variant

    Dim lngLastRow          As Long

    lngLastRow = LastRow(wksCurr, intCol)

    If lngLastRow >= intTop Then
        GetData = wksCurr.Cells(intTop, intCol).Resize(lngLastRow - intTop + 1, intCols).Value
    Else
        ReDim arrTemp(1 To 1, 1 To intCols)
        GetData = arrTemp
    End If

Proc_Exit:

    Exit Function

Proc_Error:

    Select Case Err
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Error " & CStr(Err) & ": " & Err.Description
            Resume Proc_Exit
    End Select

    Exit Function

End Function

Public Function LastRow(ByVal wksCurr As Excel.Worksheet, ByVal intCol As Integer) As Long

    Dim lngLastRow          As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    lngLastRow = wksCurr.Columns(intCol).Find( _
        What:="*", After:=wksCurr.Cells(1, intCol), _
        MatchCase:=False, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    If Err <> 0 Then
        lngLastRow = 0
        Err.Clear
    End If

    LastRow = lngLastRow

End Function

Public Function Loadscp(ByVal varList As Variant, Optional ByVal intCol As Integer = 1, _
    Optional ByVal intCols As Integer = 1, Optional ByVal strDelim As String = ".") As Scripting.Dictionary

    Dim scpList             As Scripting.Dictionary

    Dim arrVals             As Variant

    Dim lngLastRow          As Long
    Dim lngRow              As Long
    Dim intABSCol           As Integer
    Dim intColCurr          As Integer
    Dim strVal              As String
    Dim intRngCol           As Integer

    Set Loadscp = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Loadscp.CompareMode = vbTextCompare

    intABSCol = Abs(intCol)
    If IsArray(varList) Then
        arrVals = varList
    ElseIf TypeName(varList) = "Range" Then
        intRngCol = varList.Column
        lngLastRow = LastRow(varList.Parent, intCol)

        If lngLastRow > varList.Row Then
            arrVals = varList.Offset(1, intABSCol - 1).Resize(lngLastRow - varList.Row, 1)
        End If
    ElseIf TypeName(varList) = "Dictionary" Then
        Set scpList = varList
        ReDim arrVals(1 To scpList.Count, 1 To 1)
        For lngRow = 1 To scpList.Count
            arrVals(lngRow, 1) = scpList.Keys(lngRow - 1)
        Next lngRow
    End If

    If IsArray(arrVals) Then
        For lngRow = LBound(arrVals, 1) To UBound(arrVals, 1)
            strVal = arrVals(lngRow, intCol)
            For intColCurr = intCol + 1 To intCol + intCols - 1
                strVal = strVal & strDelim & arrVals(lngRow, intColCurr)
            Next intColCurr
            If Not Loadscp.Exists(strVal) Then
                Loadscp.Item(strVal) = lngRow
            End If
        Next lngRow
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185028/discussion-on-answer-by-wallyeye-compare-dynamic-range-to-a-dynamic-range-in-ano).